# changing the value of a column in a table based on the value of another column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table that is the "Class" table:

| class_size | class_number | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 4005 |
|  | 1 | 4007 |
|  | 2 | 4001 |
|  | 3 | 4010 |

I want the "class_size" column to be generated automatically based on the other two columns.
I have tried the following SQL statement, but it doesn't work:

```
update Class 
set class_size=totalSize 
where totalSize,Cnum in (Select class_number as Cnum ,count(student_id) as totalSize 
from Class
group by class_number)
and class_number = Cnum;
```

I really appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem, as I tried many different statements and still I cannot get it right.

Comment: Would you state how to calculate class size?

Comment: I calculate the class size based on the number of people taking it. for example in the table I showed, two people with student IDs 4005 and 4001 are in the class_number 2, so the class size of the class_number 2 is 2. On the other hand, only one person with the student ID 4010 is in the class_number 3, so the class_size of the class_number 3 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

here is the syntax :

```
 update class
 inner join (
    select class_number, count(*) totalSize
    from class
    group by class_number
 ) cc on class.class_number = cc.class_number
 set class.class_size = totalSize
```